# Find the probability that the sum of two randomly chosen positive numbers.... followed by some conditions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find the probability that the sum of two randomly chosen positive numbers (both $\le 1$) will not exceed $1$ and that their product will be $\le \frac{2}{9}$

**My input**

I just solved a problem in which we choose two points on a unit length line segment and a condition was given that three segments made by these two points must be greater than $\frac{1}{4}$

Similarly I solved this problem as:

Considering $AB$ as a line segment of length $1$ unit.
Same situation is here as we have to choose two numbers(As I took points on line). Also distance cant be negative. Therefor I chose two points such that there sum doesn't succeed $1$ and product is $\le \frac{2}{9}$. Two points are chose between $AB$ as $XY$ now length of $AX=x$ ,$XY=y$, And then I just applied condtions as follows: 
$x+y<1$ , $XY\le \frac{2}9$.

[image]

I have doubts.
Is this approach is correct?
I don't have its answer behind my book and that's why I didn't calculate shaded region area.  I would love to learn any other approach to solve this problem. Sorry if problem seems confusing because of my bad English.

Comment: You need to specify the distribution of the two randomly chosen numbers. Are they uniformly distributed?

Comment: Presumably your are using a uniform distribution in which case your approach is a good one.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I assumed that here.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you please confirm if this region will be the correct answer of it ? Then I ll calculate it in the answer section here.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that. I believe the approach you'd like to take should work.

Comment: @Damn1o1: The area of the region is the probability.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok I am just calculating it. And do you have any other idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Damn1o1: I don't. Note that you just need to calculate the area of the small chord bound area. Might be easier to rotate everything by ${ \pi \over 4}$.

Comment: @copper.hat You meant area of triangle - semi circle like region  ?

Comment: I mean the area between the blue & red lines. The triangle has area ${1 \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat  I wrote these constraints in desmos. Common region is the one Ishaded yellow. I am confused.

Comment: @copper.hat You confirm ?

Comment: There is a triangle and a little half banana like area. The probability is the area of the triangle less the half banana area.

Comment: @copper.hat Means I stand corrected ?

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking. You want to compute the yellow area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment:** You have a path to the answer; this is just a way to confirm
you are on the right track without actually working the problem.

I assume you have independent random variables $X$ and $Y,$ each distributed $\mathsf{Unif}(0, 1).$ And you seek $P(X+Y \le 1, XY \le 2/9),$ where as usual the comma means intersection.

Here is a simulation in R statistical software of 100,000 independent $X$'s and $Y$'s that illustrates the problem and your approach. [This method of getting
the answer by simulation is sometimes called 'Monte Carlo integration'. It is
mainly used for problems that are too messy to handle with ordinary Riemann integration (often in more than 2 dimensions).
*You should use ordinary integration for your answer*.]

```
set.seed(731);  m = 10^5;  x = runif(m);  y = runif(m)
A = (x + y <= 1);  B = (x*y <= 2/9) # A and B are logical vectors of TRUEs and FALSEs.
mean(A);  mean(B);  mean(A & B)     # mean of a logical vector is its proportion of TRUEs.
[1] 0.50086  # aprx P(A) = 1/2
[1] 0.55795  # aprx P(B)
[1] 0.48821  # aprx answer P(A & B)
```

Because of the order in which I have plotted the 100,000 points below, it is the percentage
of yellow ones that you want, as in your diagram. (About 0.488.)

```
plot(x, y, pch=".")
  points(x[B], y[B], pch=".", col="red")        # Read [ ] as "such that"
  points(x[A], y[A], pch=".", col="green2")
  points(x[A&B], y[A&B], pch=".", col="yellow")
```

[image]

For an exact solution it may be easiest to subtract the area of the green
'nibble' from 1/2. (As @copperhat has suggested.)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to compute the area of the triangle ($={1 \over 2}$) and subtract the area between
the red and blue lines.

The red and blue lines are $y= {2 \over 9x}$ and $y = 1-x$. Equating and
solving the resulting quadratic gives the bounds of integration
${1 \over 2} (1 \pm {1 \over 3})$. Hence the little area is
$\int_{{1 \over 2} (1 - {1 \over 3})}^{{1 \over 2} (1 + {1 \over 3})} (1-x-{2 \over 9x}) dx = {1 \over 6}-{2 \over 9} \ln 2 $.

The probability is then ${1 \over 3}+{2 \over 9} \ln 2 \approx 0.487$.

Comment: Simulation with a million iterations (too many for a nice figure) agrees with this to three places. (+1) Also clear and to the point.

Comment: That's what I calculated. I don't know how I got confused with you in chat. :)